# Print the first, second occurred character in a list

Tags: python, algorithm

I working on a simple algorithm which prints the first character who occurred twice or more.

```
for eg:

string ='abcabc'
output = a

string = 'abccba'
output = c

string = 'abba'
output = b
```

what I have done is:

```
string = 'abcabc'
s = []

for x in string:
     if x in s:
          print(x)
          break
     else:
          s.append(x)


output: a
```

But its time complexity is O(n^2), how can I do this in O(n)?

Comment: how did you reach on conclusion that it is taking `O(n^2)` ?

Comment: Gahan: It is; once `n` for `for`, times once `n` for `in` over list.

Comment: @Gahan not much aware about complexity, but i think it is O(n^2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dictionaries

```
string = 'abcabc'
s = {}

for x in string:
    if x in s:
        print(x)
        break
    else:
        s[x] = 0
```

or use sets

```
string = 'abcabc'
s = set()

for x in string:
    if x in s:
        print(x)
        break
    else:
        s.add(x)
```

both dictionaries and sets use indexing and search in O(1)

Comment: Note: changing `s` to `set` leads to amortized time complexity equal to `O*(n)`. The worst case time compelxity is still `O(n^2)`

Comment: @abc: Fair point. Very theoretical, as dictionaries are quite unlikely to conflict at that degree... but unlikely is still possible.

Answer (score 4):

Change `s = []` to `s = set()` (and obviously the corresponding `append` to `add`). `in` over set is O(1), unlike `in` over list which is sequential.

Alternately, with regular expressions (O(n^2), but rather fast and easy):

```
import re
match = re.search(r'(.).*\1', string)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

The regular expression `(.).*\1` means "any character which we'll remember for later, any number of intervening characters, then the remembered character again". Since regexp is scanned left-to-right, it will find `a` in `"abba"` rather than `b`, as required.

Comment: on the other hand, set add operation always check for existence of value hence it will add a bit of overhead compared to list append (negligible if not large input size)

Comment: @Gahan: OP asked for O(n) solution (i.e. a more scalable solution), not a faster solution. (Then again, the regexp solution is actually just faster, not more scalable.)

Comment: @Amadan could you join this [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179811/query) I have a query related to your given explaination